# TikZ multiple loops on one node

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am attempting to draw a single node with several loops, of various sizes, positions, and labels on them. I can do some rough work on it, although it has a few problems. I looked at the documentation for loops in the manual (52.4 Loops). This got me started by I don't know how to modify the options not discussed in that section.

Currently, I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \tikzset{every loop/.style={min distance=10mm,looseness=10}}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node [] (star) {$*$} ;
        \path[->] (star) edge [in=70,out=100,loop] node {$a$} ();
        \path[->] (star) edge  [in=0,out=30,loop] node {$b$} ();
       %\path[->] (star) edge [in=0,out=100,loop] node{$a \cdot b$} ();
        \path[->] (star) edge  [loop below] node {e} ();
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Two things I want to do.

1. Move the labels for "a" and "b" so that they're appropriately not cut off by the loop. I believe this is an artifact of the tikzset command, but I do not know how to get nice sized loops *and* good labels.
2. I want to have a loop from where "a" starts to where "b" ends to be the composition of them. Naturally, this would be best if it is bigger and sort of encompasses the pair "a" and "b". This is the commented out path.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: For 1): use auto: `node[auto] {b}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Add `auto` to the node options.
2. Instead of an `edge`, you can use a `to` path for a loop with a larger value for `distance`.

The code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \tikzset{every loop/.style={min distance=10mm,looseness=10}}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node [] (star) {$*$} ;
        \path[->] (star) edge [in=70,out=100,loop] node[auto] {$a$} ();
        \path[->] (star) edge  [in=0,out=30,loop] node[auto] {$b$} ();
        \path[->,draw] (star) to  [in=-10,out=110,loop,distance=4.5cm] node[auto] {$a\cdot b$} (star);
        \path[->] (star) edge  [loop below] node[auto] {e} ();
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]